# Get the most recent 2 entries for each group based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, greatest-n-per-group

I am using MySQL 5.7 database with the following columns

- item_symbol
- source_date
- price

I have composite primary keys which are a combination of `item_symbol`  and `source_date`. I have around 100k entries in the table.

My question here is, for each `item_symbol`, I would like to select `item_symbol` and `price` for the most recent (based on source date) 2 entries from the table.

An example of my table:

| item_symbol | price | source_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20.1 | 2021-06-10 |
| A | 18.2 | 2021-06-11 |
| A | 10.9 | 2021-06-13 |
| A | 21.0 | 2021-06-15 |
| B | 88.2 | 2021-06-10 |
| B | 60.9 | 2021-06-11 |
| B | 78.16 | 2021-06-13 |
| B | 79.0 | 2021-06-15 |

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! In future, when asking questions such as these, could you please provide a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) along with your question? This provides a single source of truth, means that there is less chance for errors and eliminates duplication of effort! Help us to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to my favourite MySQL "tips and tricks" site [here](http://artfulsoftware.com/) and went to the [common queries link](http://artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php) and looked for the [Top N per group](http://artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104&m=0) section. The **great** thing about this site is that it tells you how to do stuff in MySQL for **all** versions - well, going back at least to MySQL 5.5 - and if you're still running that, well...

I came up with the following adapted from above (all of the DDL, DML and SQL below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ecf9fcc6478c8bff8451a0013cff8c1b)):

I used the DDL and DML from @nbk, kudos to him (and +1):

```
CREATE TABLE item
(
  item_symbol CHAR(1), 
  price       DECIMAL(10,2), 
  source_date DATE
);
```

and populate it:

```
INSERT INTO item
(item_symbol, price, source_date)
VALUES
('A', 20.1, '2021-06-10'),
('A', 18.2, '2021-06-11'),
('A', 10.9, '2021-06-13'),
('A', 21.0, '2021-06-15'),
('B', 88.2, '2021-06-10'),
('B', 60.9, '2021-06-11'),
('B', 78.16, '2021-06-13'),
('B', 79.0, '2021-06-15');
```

MySQL allows the use of user variables which are a godsend when you don't have capabilities such as the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) window function which would have made this query trivial. I would **strongly** urge you to upgrade to version 8, it has many other goodies - CTEs, CHECK constraints...

Anyway, I'll demonstrate the steps, partly to explain them to you, and partly to explain them to myself! :-)

```
SELECT
  item_symbol, price, source_date,
  IF 
  (
    @prev <> item_symbol,
    @row_num := 1,
    @row_num := @row_num + 1
  ) AS my_rank,
  @prev := item_symbol
FROM item
JOIN 
  (
    SELECT @row_num := NULL, @prev := 0
  ) AS r
ORDER BY item_symbol, source_date DESC, price DESC;
```

Result:

```
item_symbol     price   source_date     my_rank     @prev := item_symbol
          A     21.00   2021-06-15            1     A
          A     10.90   2021-06-13            2     A
          A     18.20   2021-06-11            3     A
          A     20.10   2021-06-10            4     A
          B     79.00   2021-06-15            1     B
          B     78.16   2021-06-13            2     B
          B     60.90   2021-06-11            3     B
          B     88.20   2021-06-10            4     B
8 rows
```

So, we have the items ('A', 'B') order by date `DESC` (most recent first) with the price. Note that 12 lines of that query could be replaced by one `ROW_NUMBER()` function line!

So, now we wrap that in a query, pulling out those results whose `my_rank` value is <= 2 - which gives us the two most recent dates!

```
SELECT item_symbol, price, source_date, my_rank  -- this last one is not 
FROM                                             -- required - for clarity...
(
  SELECT
    item_symbol, price, source_date,
    IF 
    (
      @prev <> item_symbol,
      @row_num := 1,
      @row_num := @row_num + 1
    ) AS my_rank,
    @prev := item_symbol
    FROM item
    JOIN (SELECT @row_num := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r
    ORDER BY item_symbol, source_date DESC, price DESC  -- in case of ties!
) AS t
WHERE t.my_rank <= 2
ORDER BY item_symbol, source_date DESC; -- change this as required
```

Result:

```
item_symbol     price   source_date     my_rank
          A     21.00   2021-06-15            1
          A     10.90   2021-06-13            2
          B     79.00   2021-06-15            1
          B     78.16   2021-06-13            2
```

I would suggest that you spend some time browsing the artful softare site!

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one price for one date you have to expand teh soltion and add a row_number which are made in Mysql 5,7 with @ variqables

> ```
> CREATE TABLE item
>     (`item_symbol` varchar(1), `price` DECIMAL(10,2), `source_date` Date)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO item
>     (`item_symbol`, `price`, `source_date`)
> VALUES
>     ('A', 20.1, '2021-06-10'),
>     ('A', 18.2, '2021-06-11'),
>     ('A', 10.9, '2021-06-13'),
>     ('A', 21.0, '2021-06-15'),
>     ('B', 88.2, '2021-06-10'),
>     ('B', 60.9, '2021-06-11'),
>     ('B', 78.16, '2021-06-13'),
>     ('B', 79.0, '2021-06-15')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT i.`item_symbol`, `price` 
> FROm item i INNER JOIN (SELECT `item_symbol`,MAX(`source_date`) maxdate FROM item  GROUP By `item_symbol`) t1
> ON i.`item_symbol` = t1.`item_symbol` AND i.`source_date` = t1.maxdate
> ```
>
> ```
> item_symbol | price
> :---------- | ----:
> A           | 21.00
> B           | 79.00
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `item_symbol`, `price`,rn
> FROM(SELECT  `price` ,`source_date`
> , IF(@id =  `item_symbol`,@rn:= @rn +1,@rn := 1) As rn ,@id :=  `item_symbol` as item_symbol 
> FROM item , (SELECT @rn := 0, @id := 0) t1 ORDER BY `item_symbol`,`source_date` DESC) t2
> WHERE rn <= 2
> ```

> ```
> item_symbol | price | rn
> :---------- | ----: | -:
> A           | 21.00 |  1
> A           | 10.90 |  2
> B           | 79.00 |  1
> B           | 78.16 |  2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ece916419a8a95782eb8923e782db530)*

Comment: Hi @nbk, Thank you for your response. The above query returns only the most recent price per item. However, I want the 2 most recent prices per item.

For example, the output should be
'A','10.9',
'A', '21.0
'B', 78.16
'B', 79.0

Comment: i missed that part

Comment: Hi @nbk, the above query you provided does not provide the most recent 2. The output should be the output should be 'A','10.9', 'A', '21.0 'B', 78.16 'B', 79.0

It looks like the current query only provides the top two

Comment: @user782400 So i add the correct sporting

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to pull this one off by using something alike:

```
select [I].field1, [I].field2 ,[MR].Price]
from item [I]
cross apply ( 
        select top (2) Price from Item [s] where [s.].key = [I].Key 
        order by [S].DateField desc
         ) MR
```

Just out of mind, so adjust with your columns/tables.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the dba.se. While your enthusiasm is appreciated, you **do** know that `CROSS APPLY` is a SQL Server concept? Also, `LATERAL JOIN`s (the SQL Standard's syntax) have only been introduced into MySQL [since 8.0.14](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html).